# Typescript promise.all multiple definitions

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm expecting this code, in Typescript 2.2:

```
Promise.all([1, true]).then(([x]) => x + 1);
```

to return 2, but it doesn't. This is what happens instead:
[image: Error in visual studio code]

After doing a bit of digging, I noticed typescript has 2 files with `Promise.all` definitions,

`lib.es2015.promise.d.ts` defines it this way:

```
all<T1, T2>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
```

`lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts` defines it this way:

```
all<TAll>(values: Iterable<TAll | PromiseLike<TAll>>): Promise<TAll[]>;
```

The problem, in my case, is that the compiler is using the iterable version.

I'm using `tsconfig.json` with this setting:

```
{
...
"lib": ["dom", "es2017"]
}
```

So my question is, how would I fix this? Coerce `Promise.all` type? Make the compiler choose my preferred type definition?

Comment: Why does it return `3`, instead of `2`?

Comment: :) oopsy, fixing

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to have resolved the issue:

```
"lib": ["dom", "es2015.promise", "es2017"],
```